# What's the best way to set which image loads as a splash screen in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been doing some development for a small android application. Currently it loads a splash screen that looks really good in landscape mode, but seems... compressed when opened in portrait mode (I know this is due to the scaleType I'm using).

I'm using fitXY as my scale type to make sure the image fills the screen. There's a webview behind the image that is doing some prep work while this is happening. When the prep work finishes, I set the imageView's visibility to View.GONE to 'hide' my splash screen.

What I'd like to be able to do is change which android:src value I use depending on whether the app starts in portrait or landscape mode. In iOS, this is actually fairly easy to do because of how xCode handles splash screens. Is there such a thing as 'conditional' layouts? I.E, if in portrait mode, do this, otherwise load a different image?

Or would the only way to do something like this to have two separate image views on top of each other, and hide the corresponding ones I don't want? There has to be a better way to do this.

I currently have the following as part of my layout file:

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
  android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
  android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: Yes, you can use "conditional" layouts and/or drawables. Read up on it here: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could  have two version  of splash image,one for landscape mode and other for portrait, then you must place layouts with images in `layout` and `layout-land` res folders. you can refer to [`Supporting multiple screens`](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

Comment: I had to tweak some of my other settings but the information provided in the link was very useful. Thank you!